# wpf CombineGeometry always closes the path, even if one of the two paths isn't closed

Tags: c#, wpf

Why is it closed after combining graphics by `CombinedGeometry` ?

xaml

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

codebehind:

```
var path1 = new Path
{
    Stroke = Brushes.Orange,
    StrokeThickness = 1,
    Data = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L80,80 L0,80")
};
var path2 = new Path
{
    Stroke = Brushes.IndianRed,
    StrokeThickness = 1.2,
    Data = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(0, 0), 60, 60)
};

// path1.Data = new CombinedGeometry(
//     GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, path1.Data, path2.Data);

canvas.Children.Add(path1);
canvas.Children.Add(path2);
```

The result:

[image]

When the code of the comment line is uncommented

[image]

Why not a graphic with no blue marker line below?

[image]

Comment: What would you expect to become, if both paths would be not closed?

Comment: [CombinedGeometry combines the area specified by two geometries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks), so you get the intersection of a triangle in path1 and a circle in path2, which is a a circular sector.

Comment: Depending on your requirements you can try a `Clip` property. So set `path1.Clip` to the `EllipseGeometry`

Comment: Or simply draw a Line on top of the circle. Either calculate the appropriate endpoint, or rotate a Line around its start point by its RenderTransform.